# String pool and String[]

Tags: java, string, caching, string-pool

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = "aaa" + i;
        }

    System.out.println(arr[0] == "aaa0"); // false 
    String s = "aaa0";
    System.out.println(s == arr[0]); // false 
    }
```

I have a few question regarding the topic could help me to understand

1. What are logins behind the fact that String from string arrays don't automatically go to Sting pool, unlike string literals?
2. Do I correctly understand that only string literals go to the String pool implicitly ?
3. Do I correctly understand that string array from ***public static void main*** **( public static void main(String[] args) )**  is not go to the String pool too ?

Comment: It's not because it's in an array. It's because you're dynamically creating those `String`s (`arr[i] = "aaa" + i`).

Comment: @mstorkson he's talking about string pools though, so that is necessary to show his thinking.

Comment: @mstorkson  In my case, making comparison through == important to show string pool action ; through equals() everything will be "true" - the string in String pool and outside it.

Comment: **#2:** Correct. --- **#1:** See #2. --- **#3:** Correct, aka see #2.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler transforms that for loop under the covers!

And the resulting bytecode will use a new StringBuilder for each loop iteration... Resulting in "newly" created string objects!

Meaning; in "reality; your loop looks "more" like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("aaa");
  builder.append(i);
  arr[i] = builder.toString();
}
```

(see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) on the theoretical background)

That is one of the reasons that using == to compare strings has such a bad reputation... As it tends to lead to unexpected results.

And regarding your comment: the point is not the array you are using (where: you should **not** be writing into the array passed to main - you can, but it is bad practice).

Comment: Thx for your attention ! what about public static void main ( String[] args )? args String arr has the same logic ? Or it is some kind exception for the compiler regarding my question ?

Comment: You are very welcome. I made some updates, and in case you like my answer, please consider accepting at some point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `intern()` method to enforce String pooling, i.e. to store only one copy of each distinct string value.
Check this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = ("aaa" + i).intern();
    }

    System.out.println(arr[0] == "aaa0"); 
    String s = "aaa0";
    System.out.println(s == arr[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` if you want to compare **THE CONTENT**  of two objects. Here are more of an explication

> The “==” operator
>
> In Java, when the “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it
>   checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In
>   other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically
>   references to the same memory location.
>
> The equals() method
>
> The equals method is defined in the Object class, from which every
>   class is either a direct or indirect descendant. By default, the
>   equals() method actually behaves the same as the “==” operator –
>   meaning it checks to see if both objects reference the same place in
>   memory. But, the equals method is actually meant to compare the
>   contents of 2 objects, and not their location in memory.

```
System.out.println(arr[0].equals("aaa0")); // It give you True
System.out.println(s == arr[0]); // It give you false
```